# setStyle to a specific Vector layer

Tags: openlayers, style, feature-layer

I am trying to creat a webmapping application to make the client to change the style of a specific Layer like this :

```
var ab =new ol.layer.Vector({
  name:'ab',
  source: vectorSource,
  style: new ol.style.Style({
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({color: '#41f46e', width: 1}),
     fill : new ol.style.Fill({ color:'#4286f4'})
  })
});
var map = new ol.Map({
  layers: [ ab],
  target: document.getElementById('map'),
  view: new ol.View({
    center: [-1095791.453557, 3422374.879112],
    maxZoom: 19,
    zoom: 5
  })
});
```

I did found a code from https://github.com/weskamm/ol3vectortiles to change color style after selecting a feature in the map. but what i want is to change style directly to the layer `ab`:

```
    var styleFeaturesBox = document.getElementById('stylefeatures'),
        styler = document.getElementById('stylecontainer');

    styleFeaturesBox.onchange = function(evt) {
        if (styleFeaturesBox.checked) {
            if ($('.minicolors-input').length === 0) {
                $('#colorpicker').minicolors({
                    control: 'wheel',
                    inline: true,
                    change: function(hex) {
                        handleFeatureSelection(hex);
                    }
                });
            }
            styler.style.display = 'block';
        } else {
            styler.style.display = 'none';
        }
    };

var handleFeatureSelection = function(hex) {
    var selectCtrl = map.getInteractions().getArray().
        filter(function(i){return i instanceof ol.interaction.Select;})[0],
        selectedFeature = selectCtrl.getFeatures().getArray()[0];

    if (selectedFeature) {
        var type = selectedFeature.get('type'),
            lArr = map.getLayers().getArray()[0].getLayers(),
            layer;

        // determine the layer
        lArr.forEach(function(l) {
            if (l instanceof ol.layer.Image && l.getVisible()) {
                var feats = l.getSource().getSource().getFeatures();
                for (var i = 0; i < feats.length; i++) {
                    if (feats[i] === selectedFeature) {
                        layer = l;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        if (layer === 'ab') {
            layer.getSource().setStyle([new ol.style.Style({
                fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                  color: hex
                }),
                stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                  color: '#B3B3B3'
                })
            })]);

       } 
        layer.getSource().changed();
    }
};
```